# C++ How to memcpy int to char[]

Tags: c++

I want to convert time from int to string in a fast way.The `sprintf` is too slow. I write a test code like this:

```
int year = 2020;
int month = 8;
int day = 16;
char* log = "test log";
char output[1024];
char timeformat[] = "[0000:00:00] ";
int n = strlen(timeformat);
/*------------------1start---------------*/
for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; ++j) {
        timeformat[4-j] += year%10;
        year /= 10;
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < 2; ++j) {
        timeformat[7-j] += month%10;
        month /= 10;
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < 2; ++j) {
        timeformat[10-j] += day%10;
        day /= 10;
    }
    memcpy(output, timeformat, n);
    memcpy(output+n,log, strlen(log));
}
/*------------------1end-----------------*/

/*------------------2start---------------*/
for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; ++i) {
    sprintf(mem,"%d:%d:%d %s",year,month,day,log);
}
/*------------------2end-----------------*/
```

The first code cost 2~3seconds for average, and the second is much more slower than first one for 13~20s.
But the first code is too ugly. Is there any beautiful way to convert `int` to `char*`?

Comment: Write a function to do the work in your first snippet.

Comment: You probably should be consistent in calling your goal a "string" -- or even better, a "C-style string". There are other conversions to `char*` and `char[]` that are not what you want. For example, the expression `reinterpret_cast<char*>(&year)` converts an `int` to `char*` in a useful way, but not useful for your purposes. (On a related note, "`memcpy`" is similarly not what you want.)

Comment: Your problem is one of optimization (likely meaning compiler optimization level) than choosing something other than `sprintf()`. You will be hard pressed to write a routine that converts `int` to `char*` and then concatenates the string any faster than `sprintf()` can. (there's almost 40 years of optimization in that routine). You may also look at populating a `struct tm {..}` and using `asctime()` or converting date to `time_t` and using `ctime()`. You can test all 3, but make sure you are using at least `-O2` optimization.

Comment: `strlen(log)` doesn't belong in the loop, it never changes.